# Protractor is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: protractor, azure-devops

I've been trying to set up Protractor with Visual Studio Team Services and I set up a local agent to run a .bat file to run my protractor test. When it runs it gives me an error message:`'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I'm having the build install protractor and webdriver-manager globally, and I checked the location of the installations and I can confirm that they are there. I thought it might be a problem with the PATH variable, but I've checked and it correctly points to the npm folder where everything is installed.

There's no problem when I try to run the batch file locally.

I've looked around for other solutions but other people who have gotten this error message have been using Jenkins, which has a NodeJS plugin that solves the problem, but VSTS doesn't have this plugin.

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that you can change build agent service to your account. (Local service > Double click your agent service> Select Log On> Change account)

Another way is that you can add `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm` to Path System variable (not User variables), after that you may need to restart your machine.